# Physical manifold with a natural linear connection on them

Tags: general-relativity, classical-mechanics, differential-geometry, gauge-theory, classical-field-theory

Of course in many situation a manifold raised from a physical situation (like spacetime or configuration manifold and so on) are really much more richer than an abstract manifold. for example phase space is a symplectic manifold in a natural way.

I want (all main) examples of manifolds which have naturally a linear connection on them. (one example is given on page 247 of the book GRAVITATION by Wheeler and others: spacetime. and as I want they explain how Equivalence Principe produce this conncetion)

(may be examples will determine I would tag this question to what branches)

Answer (score 1):

1. On an arbitrary [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold) $(M,g)$ there exists a unique connection $\nabla$ that is both metric and torsionfree, namely the [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection).
2. On an arbitrary [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) $(M,\omega)$ there exist infinitely many connections $\nabla$ that are both symplectic and torsionfree.

Comment: above propositions are rather mathematical and are trivial in context of my question. as a nice example, the book GRAVITATION explains how Newtonian spacetime "has no metric but" have a natural connection. as title says I want "Physical" explanation how connection itself arise from physical structure. @Qmechanic

Comment: MTW seem to say that one can go back and forth between the notions of connection, parallel transport & geodesics.

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical definition of a manifold is as follows:

> A manifold is an object which locally looks like a Euclidean space.
>
> A manifold of dimension d locally looks like $R^d$ which is the Euclidean space in d dimension.

Now let's looks at some more real like example. So, our aim is to find objects which looks locally like a Euclidean space. If we think in this direction then we see that most the object surrounding us are some manifolds of 2 dimensions.

> For example, a chalk - if we look at the surface of the chalk. Locally it resembles a 2 dimensional sheet.
>
> A table- Its surface also looks like a sheet which is like $R^2$.
>
> A thread - It looks locally like a line. So we can call it a 1 dimensional manifold.

So mathematically, if we have such an object on which we locally regain the Euclidean structure is a manifold. More rigorous definition would require you to define a map from a local region of a manifold to a small region of, say $R^d$ if the manifold is of dimension d.